# Why is my Systemd unit loaded, but inactive (dead)?

Tags: systemd

I'm trying to set up [Graphite](http://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) on my server. I can start the Carbon Cache daemon no problem with `sudo /opt/graphite/bin/carbon-cache.py start`, but I'm struggling to run it as a Systemd unit.

Here's what I have in my service file, `graphite.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Carbon for Graphite

[Service]
ExecStart=/opt/graphite/bin/carbon-cache.py start

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

But when I start the unit I get the following status:

```
$ systemctl status graphite.service            
* graphite.service - Carbon for Graphite
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/graphite.service; enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Fri 2014-06-13 18:44:11 UTC; 2s ago
  Process: 4525 ExecStart=/opt/graphite/bin/carbon-cache.py start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 4525 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Jun 13 18:44:11 MEADOW systemd[1]: Started Carbon for Graphite.
```

Journalctl yields no more information.

**How should I interpret and debug units with a status of "inactive (dead)...(code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)"?** I've seen failed units before, but this one is successfully loaded yet not running and I don't know what that means.

Comment: It means systemd has completed its job. Shouldn't there be a `Type=` option? See `man systemd.service` for an appropriate type.

Comment: That makes sense. All I had to do was add `Type=forking` to the `[Service]` section.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Per jasonwryan's comment, while the default `Type=simple` works for many Systemd service files, it does not work when the script in `ExecStart` launches another process and completes, as is the case with graphite's carbon-cache.py. In these cases you need to explicitly specify `Type=forking` in the `[Service]` section so that Systemd knows to look at the spawned process rather than the initial one.

As explained in `man systemd.service`:

> If set to forking, it is expected that the process configured with
>   ExecStart= will call fork() as part of its start-up. The parent
>   process is expected to exit when start-up is complete and all
>   communication channels are set up. The child continues to run as the
>   main daemon process. This is the behavior of traditional UNIX daemons.
>   If this setting is used, it is recommended to also use the PIDFile=
>   option, so that systemd can identify the main process of the daemon.
>   systemd will proceed with starting follow-up units as soon as the
>   parent process exits.

### Graphite-Specific Answer

While the above solved my Systemd issue, I quickly ran into graphite-specific issues (with Twisted) and ended up going back to the default `Type`.

#### Graphite < 0.9.12

In previous versions of Graphite one can only avoid forking by using the `--debug` option:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=/opt/graphite/bin/carbon-cache.py --debug start
```

#### Graphite >= 0.9.13

In [this pull request](https://github.com/graphite-project/carbon/pull/144) a `--no-daemon` option was merged:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=/opt/graphite/bin/carbon-cache.py --no-daemon start
```