# Systemd user units fail to auto-start

Tags: systemd

The unit file works when manually started. `systemctl --user enable` does not auto-start the service after user login.

## Unit File

```
[Unit]
Description = VNC Duplicate Display RDP
After = default.target

[Service]
Type = simple
ExecStart = /opt/tigervnc/usr/bin/x0vncserver -passwordfile /etc/.vncpasswd -display :0
TimeoutSec = 30
RestartSec = 10
Restart = always

[Install]
WantedBy = default.target
```

I have reloaded and reenabled this unit

```
$ systemctl --user daemon-reload
$ systemctl --user reenable x0vncserver
```

## Status

Status after user login

```
● x0vncserver.service - VNC Duplicate Display RDP
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/x0vncserver.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

## Target Status

```
$ systemctl --user --type target
UNIT           LOAD   ACTIVE SUB    DESCRIPTION
basic.target   loaded active active Basic System
default.target loaded active active Default
paths.target   loaded active active Paths
sockets.target loaded active active Sockets
timers.target  loaded active active Timers

LOAD   = Reflects whether the unit definition was properly loaded.
ACTIVE = The high-level unit activation state, i.e. generalization of SUB.
SUB    = The low-level unit activation state, values depend on unit type.

5 loaded units listed. Pass --all to see loaded but inactive units, too.
To show all installed unit files use 'systemctl list-unit-files'.
```

## Manual Start

```
$ systemctl --user start x0vncserver
$ systemctl --user status x0vncserver
● x0vncserver.service - VNC Duplicate Display RDP
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/x0vncserver.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2017-08-07 18:27:00 IST; 5s ago
 Main PID: 2999 (x0vncserver)
   CGroup: /user.slice/user-1004.slice/user@1004.service/x0vncserver.service
           └─2999 /opt/tigervnc/usr/bin/x0vncserver -passwordfile /etc/.vncpasswd -display :0

Aug 07 18:27:00 Machine systemd[930]: Started VNC Duplicate Display RDP.
Aug 07 18:27:00 Machine x0vncserver[2999]: Mon Aug  7 18:27:00 2017
Aug 07 18:27:00 Machine x0vncserver[2999]:  Geometry:    Desktop geometry is set to 1920x1080+0+0
Aug 07 18:27:00 Machine x0vncserver[2999]:  Main:        XTest extension present - version 2.2
Aug 07 18:27:00 Machine x0vncserver[2999]:  Main:        Listening on port 5900
```

## References

I've looked around and found users with similar issues but none of the proposed solutions fixed my issue

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39871883/systemctl-status-shows-inactive-dead
- https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=170344
- [Why is my Systemd unit loaded, but inactive (dead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/137028/why-is-my-systemd-unit-loaded-but-inactive-dead)
- https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/4301
- https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/2690
- https://superuser.com/questions/955922/enabled-systemd-unit-does-not-start-at-boot

## Update

This happens to a particular user. `systemctl --user enable` works for at least one other user on the same device.

Comment: What does journalctl tell you?

Comment: Good question, it tells nothing. Cannot find the text `x0vncserver`

Comment: "works for at least one other user", what is the user that it works for and what are the permissions on /etc/.vncpasswd?  Also, it might only work for one user at a time if all instances attempt to listen on the same port (5900 is the default)

Comment: See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/374638/why-x0vncserver-is-not-starting-at-boot?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, what fixed it for me was using it as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/x0vncserver -PasswordFile=/home/luserid/.vnc/passwd -display=:0
```

it seems it won't start right without the `-display=:0`.

Comment: This is necessary for the `--system` bus.  However, the `--user` bus is pretty good at setting `$DISPLAY` automatically.  That's nice in case it isn't always `:0`

Answer (score 0):

To let systemd run a VNC server, that server needs two things:

1. `$DISPLAY`
2. `$XAUTHORITY`

If you are running on the user-bus (which you are), these are often set automatically.  I've found that when these variables are reliably set, I don't need to be explicit with `--display` which is good because it can change based on my configuration.  Tigervnc might be different, but I would expect it to use `$DISPLAY` if `--display` isn't specified.

So how do you ensure these are reliably set when you start your service?

These may not be set immediately if your user logs in before the X-server is fully up and running.  I find this happens on systems where I use auto-login from GDM, or if I log in via SSH or a TTY before logging in via display-manager.

The solution I use on my Debian system is to only run my vnc server after Xauthority is guaranteed to be available.  I detect that with a `*.path` unit:

```
# ~/.config/systemd/user/vnc.path
[Path]
PathExists=%t/gdm/Xauthority

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target

# ~/.config/systemd/user/vnc.service
[Service]
ExecStart=x11vnc -shared -many -nopw
```

You only need to `systemctl --user enable vnc.path` for this to work.

The path unit will sit and wait for `/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority` to exist.  That will only exist AFTER your user has access to a display.  When it is created, the path unit will start `vnc.service` and your VNC server will start with `$DISPLAY` and `$XAUTHORITY` variables set automatically.

The path `%t/gdm/Xauthority` is a default path on Debian.  `%t` is short for `/run/user/1000` and I like using that short-hand because it works if your UID is not 1000.  Take a look at `echo $XAUTHORITY` if you need a different path if you're on a different distro.

---

Side-note:

The [`systemd` design](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.special.html) has some targets of interest.  `default.target` is meant to be symlinked to `graphical.target` which has some relationships with `graphical-session.target` which is implemented the desktop environment (e.g. `gnome-session.target`).

Theoretically, using `WantedBy=graphical-session.target` and `After=graphical-session.target` is a simpler and better solution to the `*.path` I mentioned, but unfortunately the implementation needs to be done by the desktop-environments, and that does not appear to have happened yet on all DEs.  I've found that `graphical-session.target` isn't raised on all desktop environments reliably, hence the `*.path` solution is my recommendation.

Comment: When I run `echo $XAUTHORITY` on Ubuntu 20 from a terminal running gnome on a remote connection, I get nothing. I do get a value for `echo $DISPLAY`