# Systemd user VNC service won't start automatically

Tags: systemd

I'm trying to start VNC server in systemd in user mode automatically after boot. Using Arch Linux running as virtual machine.

VNC server is Tiger VNC:

```
$ pacman -Qs vnc
local/tigervnc 1.9.0-1
    Suite of VNC servers and clients. Based on the VNC 4 branch of TightVNC.
```

`/home/raspi/vnc.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Remote desktop service (VNC)

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/vncserver -kill :1 > /dev/null 2>&1 || :'
ExecStart=/usr/bin/vncserver :1 -geometry 1920x1080 -alwaysshared -fg -name remote
ExecStop=/usr/bin/vncserver -kill :1

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Linger is enabled:

```
$ loginctl show-user raspi | grep -i linger
Linger=yes
```

Installed with:

```
$ systemctl --user enable /home/raspi/vnc.service
Created symlink /home/raspi/.config/systemd/user/default.target.wants/vnc.service → /home/raspi/vnc.service.
Created symlink /home/raspi/.config/systemd/user/vnc.service → /home/raspi/vnc.service.
```

Started with:

```
$ systemctl --user start vnc.service
```

I can start it and connect to it but it doesn't automatically start when system boots. I have to log in and run `systemctl --user start vnc.service` manually. What I'm missing?

Comment: It's a user service, not a system service, why would yopu expect it to start at boot?  And after user login, are you sure it's not auto started? Have you checked journalctl?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/384499/systemd-user-units-fail-to-auto-start/653118#653118

Comment: This one may also work: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/644886/vnc-server-with-gdm-login

Answer (score 0):

You are missing that your per-user service management *does not itself start at bootstrap* in the default configuration.  It starts when you first log on, the consequence of a hook by the service manager into the login system.

## Further reading

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/427917/5132
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/407863/5132