# Systemd Type=forking doesn't capture subprocess (updated, not caused by systemd)

Tags: systemd

Update:

I have solved the problem. I will share my experience here:

- The new vncsession will fork and keep check status on the child
- The child checks `/home/$USER/.vnc/`. Actually the main issue is with this folder. It seems this folder is created before, and SELinux context is different than vncsession. Remove the folder and re-create password.
- Compile tigervnc following the [RPM spec](https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/tigervnc/blob/master/f/tigervnc.spec#_31), remember that the RPM version uses prefix `/usr` but git version uses `/usr/local`.
- Replace all `perror` with `syslog(LOG_CRIT, ...` to truly capture the error message.

*The main issue is the forked process' errors are not reflected in either in `journalct -t vncsession` or `journalctl -u vncserver@:$DISPLAY`*. You need to modify vncsession's source code to find out the root cause.

Original question:

I am working with TigerVNC on Fedora 33. The latest update on TigerVNC switches from `vncserver` to `vncsession`. Systemd unit file is updated to reflect the latest change. However, I cannot start VNC with the latest systemd unit file and I am debugging it. The service runs properly (I add `-x` to the wrapper bash code to see if the vncsession was called properly) and then service turns *inactive*.

The basic structure of the unit file is:

```
Type=forking
ExecStart=/.../vncsession-start DISPLAY
```

The vncsession-start is actually a wrapper:

```bsh
...
exec /.../vncsession USER DISPLAY
```

The problem is when I `systemctl start` the service, it ends without error (only main PID is listed and ExitCode=0). But I run it in two other ways:

- run directly from bash: it runs, Xvnc launches
- modify unit file to `ExecStart=/bin/bash -cx 'strace -f vncsession USER DISPLAY'` and change `Type=simple`: Xvnc also launches

The first try is to rule out wrong vnc configurations; the second is to check SELinux setup.

The `Type=forking` handles `fork()` syscall, according to doc. I checked `vncsession` with strace, what I see is:

- bash `exec` vncsession
- vncsession calls `clone()`, **not** `fork()`
- vncsession then calls `execev()` to launch Xvnc

So my question is: what is the 1) proper `Type=` for this case, is `forking` the right choice? 2) how to debug this type of problem?

Thank you!

Comment: My goodness!  TigerVNC has got worse since 2018 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/472190/5132 .  It's a whole mess of _new_ compulsory unnecessary dæmonization, new rickety and dangerous PID files, and new "users" files now.  And all that in the name of _introducing_ systemd support.

Comment: Sigh, preliminary debugging shows the PID file contains wrong PID.