# Personalised instances of systemd sevices

Tags: systemd, template

I have four instances of a VNC server running on a Debian Buster machine for four different users.

Thanks to Apache Guacamole the users can login to their respective accounts concurrently from their remote computers via webbrowser.

Each VNC instance has their own unit file. They look someting like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=a wrapper to launch an X server for VNC
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=user2
Group=user2
WorkingDirectory=/home/user2

ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/vncserver -kill :%i > /dev/null 2>&1
ExecStart=/usr/bin/vncserver -rfbport 5902 -depth 24 -geometry 1280x800 -localhost :%i
ExecStop=/usr/bin/vncserver -kill :%i

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Note that the user, the user's home directory, and the port for the VNC server have been explicitely specified. They need to match the data in Guacamole's user-mapping file:

```
    <connection name="User1">
        <protocol>vnc</protocol>
        <param name="hostname">localhost</param>
        <param name="port">5902</param>       
        <param name="password">user2's vnc password</param>                  
    </connection>
</authorize
```

I have a very simple script running at boot time that just starts the VNC instances one at a time.

So this works for me, it's just that I don't find this too elegant. Is there a nicer way of talking systemd into multi user support? What would a vncserver@.service template file maybe look like that could handle user names and port numbers?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/644895/272848

Comment: Thank you @Stewart. I understand that Guacamole needs specific ports for the according users, so some sort of mapping would be needed. But I will give it a fresh start next week considering your post. :)