# can't start VNC server from a service, Works fine when started from terminal TigerVNC + noVNC

Tags: gnome, services, vnc, tigervnc

I have a VNC setup using TigerVNC and noVNC on my linux machine (Ubuntu 20.4). It works perfectly when started it from terminal but I want to start it from a service so that it can auto start on boot however it is not working

My service file name 'vncserver@.service' located at /etc/systemd/system looks like this

```
[Unit]
Description = VNC server
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=taisafmr15

ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/vncserver -kill :2
ExecStart=/usr/bin/vncserver :2 -geometry 1600x900 -depth 24 -localhost no
ExecStop=/usr/bin/vncserver -kill :2

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I can enable my service using

```
sudo systemctl enable vncserver@1.service
```

And It starts without any error
same for starting it

```
sudo systemctl start vncserver@1.service
```

However my vnc server don't start, running

```
sudo systemctl status vncserver@1.service
```

shows that it failed (code=exited, status=255/EXCEPTION)
looking into logs it shows it failed on ExecStart and the only error code / message I see is this (code=exited, status=255/EXCEPTION)

However when I run that command normally from my terminal my vnc server starts fine just not from a service,

Struggling with for days
Any help / recommendation would be helpful

EDIT:
My xstartup file at ~/.vnc/xstartup

```
#!/bin/sh
[-x /etc/vnc/xstartup] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[-r $HOME/.Xresources] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
```

My xstartup file at /etc/vnc/xstartup

```
#!/bin/sh
export DISPLAY=:2
test x"$SHELL" = x"" && SHELL=/bin/bash
test x"$1"     = x"" && set -- default

vncconfig -iconic &
"$SHELL" -l << EOF
export XDG_SESSION_TYPE=x11
export XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/var/lib/snapd/desktop
export XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/etc//xdg-ubuntu:/etc/xdg
export XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=ubuntu:GNOME
export DESKTOP_SESSION=/usr/share/xsessions/ubuntu.desktop
export GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE=ubuntu
dbus-launch --exit-with-session /usr/bin/gnome-session --session=ubuntu
EOF
vncserver -kill $DISPLAY
```

both xstartup files have follwoing permissions

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/vnc/xstartup
sudo chmod 777 /etc/vnc/xstartup
```

Full Error message
vncserver[7143]: Thu Apr 13 16:26:40 2023
vncserver[7143]:  ComparingUpdateTracker: 0 pixels in / 0 pixels out
vncserver[7143]:  ComparingUpdateTracker: (1:-nan ratio)
vncserver[7143]: Killing Xtigervnc process ID 6921... which seems to be deadlocked. Using SIGKILL!

vncserver[6912]: Starting applications specified in /home/tai79/.vnc/xstartup has failed.
vncserver[6912]: Maybe try something simple first, e.g.,
vncserver[6912]:         tigervncserver -xstartup /usr/bin/xterm
systemd[1]: vncserver@1.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=255/EXCEPTION
systemd[1]: vncserver@1.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

Comment: You are still missing the `XAUTHORITY` environment variable.  I would move this to the user bus to inherit this data.  Otherwise, does this answer your question?  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/653118/272848